# Five digit number with digits in ascending order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many five digit numbers of different digits can be made in which digits are in ascending order? 
Well, when i was trying to solve the problem, i tried taking cases fixing      1 in the first place and so on.. However as it is evident, the 2nd place then maybe filled by 2,3,4,5,6 which implies 5 ways. If we count 5 ways for this place, we cannot say with certainty if 3,4,5,6,7 may enter the 3rd place or not, as if the 2nd place is occupied by 6, no other possibility remains.
Then, i also saw a pattern being followed in the possible numbers which may or may not be filled in a given place, excluding one possibility after each step.. However, was unable to calculate the same.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $\displaystyle{9\choose 5} = 126$:

Each number $abcde$ is the same as choosing a subset $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ of $\{1,2,...,9\}$.

For example, the number $24579$ is the same as set $\{2,4,5,7,9\}$ and vice versa,
a set $\{1,3,4,5,8\}$ determines a number $13458$.

Comment: Your first  example seems to have got garbled.

Comment: How does this assure that the digits are in ascending order?

Comment: I just made such map that it is a bijection between  the set of numbers you want and a family of 5 element subsets in a set of firs 9 numbers. So the number of numbers you want is the same as the number of all 5 element subsets in a set $\{1,2,...9\}$.

Comment: You meant to write the number $24579$ is the same as the set $\{2, \color{red}{4}, 5, 7, 9\}$.